# Base Class "Does Not Seem to Have Been Enhanced" After Upgrade of Google App Engine SDK for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I get errors like this when attempting to run unit tests under App Engine SDK 1.2.8.  The unit tests pass under SDK 1.2.6 using the same code.

"Class com.foo.bar.BaseClass does not seem to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output"

A class which extends BaseClass IS persisted, but has the proper annotations, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread on GAE support group shows other reports of the same issue and links to a release-candidate version of ORM 1.0.4 which fixes this and another related bug: [Support Thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/78b99b013412e042/a6a7c4ee3c7d49c8?lnk=gst&q=not+enhanced&pli=1)

My errors were fixed by installing the [ORM RC](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://datanucleus-appengine.googlecode.com/files/appengine-orm-1.0.4.1.RC1.zip&usg=AFQjCNGzX7Hc7Lwsf09A5-vPNS_C6104vA) using the [method](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/HowToUpdateTheSDKWithANewPluginVersion&usg=AFQjCNHr6u5ZzFTlEri9L_hZua7vd_McKg) provided in the GAE support wiki.

Thanks to Max Ross @ Google for delivering a fix for the problem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with a different solution. After deploying I checked the console, that pointed to an error log:

> Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.appengine" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath.plugin in the classpath.

So I checked the libs in the WEB-INF folder. I found multiple versions of "datanucleus-appengine-xxx". After removing the old verions it worked again.